# Manually Sorting Data in Gridview in asp.Net Webforms

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, webforms

I am having some difficult manually sorting data on a gridview. I used a dataset and when set the AllowSort to true and also wrote the code to handle the sort based on the guide given on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting.aspx  . However, when I run my code, the data displays but when I click the header of each column, nothing happens.
here is my code

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


       string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand();


    comm.CommandText = "SELECT Count(Student.StudentID) AS StdCount, Schools.Name, Schools.StartDate, School.SchoolFees FROM Schools INNER JOIN Students ON Schools.SchoolID = Student.SchoolID WHERE School.Active = 1 GROUP BY Schools.Name, Schools.StartDate, Schools.SchoolFess ORDER BY Schools.Name ASC";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

         da.Fill(ds);

        if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

            ViewState["datable"] = dt;
        }



        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind(); 

    }
protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {

        //Retrieve the table from the session object.
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["datable"];

        if (dt != null)
        {

            //Sort the data.
            dt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + GetSortDirection(e.SortExpression);
            GridView1.DataSource = ViewState["datable"];
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

    }

    private string GetSortDirection(string column)
    {

        // By default, set the sort direction to ascending.
        string sortDirection = "ASC";

        // Retrieve the last column that was sorted.
        string sortExpression = ViewState["SortExpression"] as string;

        if (sortExpression != null)
        {
            // Check if the same column is being sorted.
            // Otherwise, the default value can be returned.
            if (sortExpression == column)
            {
                string lastDirection = ViewState["SortDirection"] as string;
                if ((lastDirection != null) && (lastDirection == "ASC"))
                {
                    sortDirection = "DESC";
                }
            }
        }

        // Save new values in ViewState.
        ViewState["SortDirection"] = sortDirection;
        ViewState["SortExpression"] = column;

        return sortDirection;
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did you debug to see what value return your function? Create a variable `string sortOrder = GetSortDirection(e.SortExpression);` and put a breakpoint there

Comment: Please don't store objects like data tables in ViewState. ViewState is not designed to be used as cache mechanism for heavy stuff. Do another query to database, or server side caching, but not viewstate.

Comment: Also, you are re-binding GridView with data on every page_load. There is no need to do it, wrap this code in `if (!Page.IsPostback)`

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick reply. I added a breakpoint like you said @Juan and I noticed that execution doesnt break at that point. It is as if the event doesnt even fire.

Comment: Thanks @Andrei, will make the corrections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind the DefaultView of the DataTable, which is this orderly, not ViewState variable.

```
protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    //Retrieve the table from the session object.
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["datable"];
    if (dt != null)
    {
        //Sort the data.
        dt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + GetSortDirection(e.SortExpression);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Rocoso. I have modified the code as you stated above, yet it still doesnt work. When I click, nothing happens just as if the event doesnt get fired. I added a breakpoint in the GridView1_Sorting code block and the breakpoint is never reached.

Comment: I just found out the EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks is set to 'true' and that is why the event isnt firing. I set it to false and the event fires. But the sort occurs just once. when I click again, the page just reloads and it doesnt sort. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just fount out where the problem is. The sorting works well now. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a [Page LifeCycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx#lifecycle_events) issue.

Every time you post back the entire Page LifeCycle runs

In your case you are retrieving and overwriting `ViewState["datable"]` on every postback, assuming of course that `if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)` evaluates to true.

And then you do this in Page Load:

```
GridView1.DataSource = ds;
```

but in your sorting routine you access:

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["datable"];
...
GridView1.DataSource = ViewState["datable"];
```

You just replaced GridView.DataSource, which initially was a DataSet, with a DataTable

Wrap your initial data Retrieval in PageLoad like this

```
if( !Page.IsPostback )
{
   // This retrieves Data once, and you persist it 
   // in the ViewState no need to Keep retrieving it 
   // unless the data has changed
}

// Rebind outside the if
GridView1.DataSource = (DataTable) ViewState["datable"];
GridView1.DataBind();
```

## Addendum

**Per Andrei** he is correct.  ViewState is a hidden field on your rendered ASPX.  View the page source in your browser and search for

```
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="" />
```

It's Ok to use as a learning aid as long as the dataset is small and doesn't contain any confidential information.

But as it's transmitted to and from your page on every postback you incur a lot of overhead.  Imagine if your DataSet contained several thousand rows.

Session State is a better option, but the Application Cache is better still.  Server Data Controls like `SqlDataSource` make use of this cache and so can you.  Access it just like ViewState:

```
ViewState["datable"] = dt;

Cache["datable"] = dt;
```

But don't go crazy with it.  ViewState, SessionState, Cookies, LocalStorage, etc all have their place, learn them.

Comment: Thanks @fnostro. I followed Andrei's advice and used a session to hold the datatable. The sort routine works now, but it just sorts in descending order and when I click again, the page reloads and doesnt sort it in ascending order.

Comment: I debugged and found out that I made a mistake of calling my sort function twice and that is the reason why the sort wasnt working well. Thanks for the help @fnostro.